# Создание расширения для вкладок Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Вот думаю как у всех кто держит много вкладок возник вопрос как это удобизировать, единственный путь который я пока что вижу это сделать вкладки вложенными, ну условно выглядит это так, есть вкладка которую называешь сам, зайдя в неё прям под этой строкой появляется вложенный набор вкладок, собственно вопрос есть ли такое (я не нашёл) и можно ли это сделать средствами Chrome , я расширений не писал, но js знаю , самое главное даёт ли Chrome такой доступ к своему интерфейсу через расширения или нет?
На картинке пример как это могло бы выглядеть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы смотрели Chrome Store? С ходу находятся: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/group-your-tabs/chaoejepfhlcelgpicelfccoiojpiofn, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp.

Comment: Это всё не то, и никак не похоже на то что я хочу, какое отношение имеет к StackOverflow? да самое прямое, если есть кто-то глубоко в теме расширений хрома то мне смогут сказать даёт ли API хрома такой доступ к браузеру или нет

Comment: ps: на вызоде нужно чтобы было как то так http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=33d201ca80060232d485b756b67b5823   то есть верхний ряд делается и называется мной, а в нижнем обычный хром с закладками, тут нужен гуру хроморасширений чтобы понять можно ли так глубоко залезть в браузер, то есть грубо говоря надо генерить странички со своими именами, это легко, но вот можно ли внутри странички запустить , условно, ещё один хром

Comment: разве что наоборот - верхний уровень вкладки хрома,а в них страницы,которые вы сами сделаете,с вашими вкладками. [Док расширений хрома](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что ты хочешь сделать функциональность вложенности табов Оперы 12 и Vivaldi?

Comment: @Nofate, думаю это не то.

Comment: @Qwertiy там это сделано не так удобно, и при кол-ве вложенных вкладок более 10-ти это становится не так удобно и быстро, хотя вивальди конечно лучше чем вообще ничего, в опере вобще слабоюзабельно сделанно, я на картинке показал как бы я это хотел видеть, http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=33d201ca80060232d485b756b67b5823 , верхнюю часть называем сами и открывая её там находятся вложенные вкладки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос понял по скриншоту из комментариев:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нативно Chrome Extensions API такой возможности не предоставляет.

Comment: Я так и понял судя по документации, надеялся что вдруг что-то проглядел.